# WPF Visibility Resource with Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, visibility, .net-4.5

I got a WPF Application using MVVM Light. In one View i got many Controls which are using the same visibility binding. Because i dont like to insert my long binding path to every control. I'd like to use a Resource...

```
<SomeControl>
  <SomeControl.Resource>
    <Visibility x:Key="myVisibilityResource" >
        <Binding Path="somePath" Converter="BoolToVisibilityConverter"></Binding>
    </Visibility>
  </SomeControl.Resource>
<SomeControl>
```

With this version i get the Error that Visibility does not support direct content. I would have to write it like this:

```
<Visibility x:Key="myVisibilityResource" >
    Collapsed
</Visibility>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you define it as a string and call it that way? <x:String x:Key="MyString">This is a resource</x:String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style in resources:

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="VisibilityStyle">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" 
 Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfFalse}}"/>
</Style>
```

Then simply add the reference to the item to hide/show.

```
<TextBlock Text="123" Style="{StaticResource VisibilityStyle}"/>
<TextBlock Text="123" Style="{StaticResource VisibilityStyle}"/>
<TextBlock Text="123" Style="{StaticResource VisibilityStyle}"/>
<TextBlock Text="123" Style="{StaticResource VisibilityStyle}"/>
```

This also works for headers of grids...

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to be able to write "Visible" or "Collapsed" in your XAML (as in your last example) you can do it by binding to and [`ObjectDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodparameters.aspx) which is uses [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to parse the given text (which can be "Visible", "Collapsed", or "Hidden"):

```
<Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="visibilityProvider"
                MethodName="Parse" 
                ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Visibility" />
                <sys:String>Visible</sys:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="button1" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource visibilityProvider}}" />

</Grid>
```

In the above code I am using an `ObjectDataProvider` to return a [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) enumeration.  The `ObjectDataProvider` calls `Enum.Parse` when binding.  The button's `Visibility` property binds to the `ObjectDataProvider`.
The `MethodParameters` property specifies the parameters for `Enum.Parse`.

Unfortunately there is no way to bind `MethodParameters` directly to an underlying ViewModel.  If you want to do this, I guess you could write your own `ObjectDataProvider` or you could use your own class/method instead of `Enum.Parse` which returns the correct `Visibility` value.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? It's not exactly what you asked for, but you would be copying less code around since you wouldn't have to include the converter every time.

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <SomeElement x:Name="Master" Visibility="{Binding somePath, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <SomeOtherElement Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Master}" />
    <SomeOtherElement Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Master}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```